# How much thermal energy, in joules per centimeter squared, is required to ignite common aerospace materials?

Tags: physics, materials, flight, nuclear-weapons, nuclear-power

How much thermal energy, measured in joules per centimeter squared, would be required to:

- melt (or ignite, if possible) commonly-used commercial airliner paint
- melt (or ignite, if possible) commonly used aerospace composites

The reason I'm asking:

I'm working on writing a nuclear-jet powered aircraft in a sci-fi setting. It uses an indirect air cycle molten-salt-cooled reactor to heat air to provide thrust without using fuel (other than the occasional reactor overhaul/nuclear fuel change-out). Radiator panels are built into its skin. It's intended to be a subsonic, long-haul cargo vehicle - not some kind of fancy supersonic jet.

I'm writing a scene where it's flying away from a nuclear explosion (at do-not-exceed speed; its radiators are overheating already), but doesn't get far enough away to avoid its radiators exploding/leaking coolant and its paint melting due to the thermal effects. How powerful would those thermal effects need to be? I imagine that radiators filled with molten salt deforming would require a lot more heat per square centimeter than paint melting.

I asked for "common aerospace materials" rather than "cutting edge" because these things are intended to be mass-produced in a relatively futuristic setting.

Comment: radiators won't be painted or made of aircraft composite. you want as little insulation on radiators as possible.

Comment: @John I meant the paint as a separate thing getting melted, and used composites as a benchmark. I'm not sure how durable radiator panels would be in comparison.

Comment: better question why does your aircraft have exposed radiators, that is extremely rare, modern aircraft use forced air scoops and internal radiators since it is far more efficient,

Comment: this paper should be helpful https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/AD0362112 EFFECTS OF NUCLEAR EXPLOSIONS ON FIGHTER AIRCRAFT COMPONENTS

Comment: @John I figured that it wouldn't have enough surface area to compensate for cooling the nuclear fission reactor that provides engine heating. IIRC, such a system hasn't actually been tested in flight (although an aircraft with such a system was flown without it activated). Also, thank you for the paper - that'll be immeasurably valuable.

Comment: flowing air is always going to cool much faster than passive radiation, counter current mechanisms a very efficient, that's why every machine that can uses them. only space craft need to rely on passive radiation. with active airflow you can stack parallel  radiators very close together because they always have fresh air to give heat too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countercurrent_exchange

Comment: @John Wouldn't you not want the radiators in the engine, though? Since this craft uses nuclear-thermal jet engines, it needs to intake cooler air and then heat and compress it. If you put the radiators in the intake, the air coming in isn't as cool, and if you put them in the exhaust, they won't be able to transfer as much excess heat out of the system.

Comment: The accepted SI unit for energy is Joule. ('small' calorie is SI, yet it is obsolete)

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE yes ideally you would be dumping your heat inside the engine to provide thrust, if for some reason you needed to shed more head you just put it on the intake. there should be no radiators exposed anywhere on the craft https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-indirect-cycle-solution_fig2_266503875

Comment: @Allan In that case, I'll edit it to "joules/cm^2".

Comment: @John It already does that; wouldn't you need extra radiators to deal with surplus?

Comment: you shouldn't the way the engines work there should not be much surplus, except maybe on landing, and even if you do you just stick them on the interior of the sides of the intake like normal jet engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How are airplanes painted?](https://aerocorner.com/blog/how-are-airplanes-painted/) enamel and epoxy.

It's difficult to find any data on the auto-ignition point for enamel, but for epoxy it's [300C](https://www.msdsdigital.com/system/files/813-501%2C%20813-502%20msds.pdf).

Carbon composite will burn at [300-500C](https://www.fire.tc.faa.gov/pdf/07-57.pdf).

For comparison, wood ignites at [380C](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0010218067900582).  So answers about when wood will spontaneously ignite will also answer the question of when aerospace materials will spontaneously ignite.

Based on [this](https://www.atomicarchive.com/resources/documents/med/med_chp17.html):

> The flash burning of the surface of objects, particularly wooden objects, occurred in Hiroshima up to a radius of 9,500 feet from X; at Nagasaki burns were visible up to 11,000 feet from X.

[Nukemap](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/) listed the "thermal radiation radius" for 3rd degree burns as 1.96km (6266ft) for Hiroshima, and 2.21km (7255 feet) for Nagasaki.  9500ft is 51% greater than 6266ft, and 11000 ft is 51% greater than 7255ft.

So:  take the distance Nukemap lists for 3rd degree skin burns, and multiply it by 1.5, and you will get the maximum distance wooden or aerospace materials might receive surface burns.

Comment: Brilliant answer - thank you. I'm going to point out that NUKEMAP-2 actually has a setting for when dry wood will burst into flames - 35 small calories per cm^2, or about 146.44 joules/cm^2. I'll use that as a conservative estimate for ignition of aerospace composites, while the 3rd-degree-burn  radius * 1.5 is the most "out-there" estimate.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE 9500/6266 = 1.51611, and 11000 / 7255 = 1.51619.  These ratios are so exact - especially when compared with the imprecision of 9500ft and 11000ft - that I suspect Nukemap used those figures of 9500ft and 11000ft as calibration.